# stimulsoft issues with WHERE

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stimulsoft

I have a report in stimulsoft, it just work fine with this query

```
SELECT Car.IDCar, Car.NameCar, Car.Code, Car.DriverName, Car.IsTruck,
  CarData.IDCarData, CarData.Start, CarData.End, CarData.Total,
  CarData.Distance, CarData.Weight, CarData.Controller, CarData.Scope,
  CarData.Description, CarData.Date
FROM Car LEFT JOIN
  CarData ON Car.IDCar = CarData.CarID
WHERE CarData.Date= '20150515'
```

But when I want to use it like bellow, it returns no data

```
SELECT Car.IDCar, Car.NameCar, Car.Code, Car.DriverName, Car.IsTruck,
  CarData.IDCarData, CarData.Start, CarData.End, CarData.Total,
  CarData.Distance, CarData.Weight, CarData.Controller, CarData.Scope,
  CarData.Description, CarData.Date
FROM Car LEFT JOIN
  CarData ON Car.IDCar = CarData.CarID
WHERE CarData.Date= '20150515' and Car.IsTruck='yes'
```

I have to mention that my data are in persian language, so the original query is >

```
WHERE CarData.Date= '20150515' and Car.IsTruck='بلی'
```

Comment: Is it N'yourtext' so that it's treated correctly as nvarchar?

Comment: Thank you! It's ok now,  I have forgotten that!